# How to eval() outside a function in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I'm not sure it is possible, but I'm looking to eval and get access to the eval code outside the scope of the function it's called in.

My current code:

```
test.importDependencies = () => 'function myDep() {}'
eval(test.importDependencies())
myDep()
```

What I would like it to be:

```
test.importDependencies = () => 'function myDep() {}'
test.importDependencies()
myDep()
```

The reason for this is I'm writing code for Google App Script and it doesn't use require, everything is in the global scope. But I want to write some unit tests in node and I don't want to use require statements in my code because it would complicate my build process.

Comment: `test.importDependencies = () => eval('function myDep() {}')`? Still, very much an X/Y problem

Comment: @CertainPerformance don't think that would work, it will eval inside the `() => {}` and not be accessible outside.